# Run gulp functions from another function?

Tags: gulp

I have 2 tasks 'something' and 'something2'. Im currently calling them separately.

```
var something = function() {
  // do something 
},
something2 = function() {
  // do something else 
}
```

How can I just call a trigger function which would call them both?

```
var trigger = function() {
  // run  something and something2
},
something = function() {
  // do something 
},
something2 = function() {
  // do someting hes
}
```

Comment: `var trigger = function() {
  something(); something2()
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tasks

```
gulp.task('Task_1', function() {
  // do something 
});

gulp.task('Task_2', function() {
  // do something else
});
```

You have two ways to run these tasks from another task.

**First**

You can run your tasks as dependencies of a third task. This in turn runs the dependencies asynchronously and then executes the content of the third task. In your case you can leave it empty

```
gulp.task('Task_3', ['Task_1', 'Task_2'],function() {
  // DO NOTHING
});
```

**Second**

You can use `gulp.start` to run your tasks withing the third task

```
gulp.task('Task_3',function() {
  // Start the following tasks
  gulp.start('Task_1');
  gulp.start('Task_2');
});
```

**Note**

I use the second approach to run tasks conditionally

```
gulp.task('Task_3',function() {
  // check condition and run appropriate task
  if(some_condition){
     gulp.start('Task_1');
  }
  else {
    gulp.start('Task_2');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is:

```
gulp.task('task_3',['task_1','task_2','more_tasks']);
```